# ASP.NET AjaxControlToolKit Accordion set active pane via javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I would like to be able to change the active pane of an accordion using javascript.

I see a behavior set_SelectedIndex but I can not seem to get it to work.

How can I find out what the supported methods are for this control?

How can I set the selected index from the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a comment on this blogpost http://disturbedbuddha.wordpress.com/2007/11/30/selecting-an-ajax-accordionpane-by-id/ which showed me how to use Accordion.AccordionBehavior.set_SelectedIndex(index);.

I am outputting a startup script from the codebehind of variables with the paneIds prefaces with a code and their index.  This allows me to set the active pane by id.